# The version of iOS on “KashodhaniPhone” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK.

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, xcode4

I complete all step to provisional but i faced "**Xcode cannot run using the selected device**." and below of this line is "**No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination**."

when i am going to organizer its show the Yellow status  please  some  one help me
he version of iOS on “KashodhaniPhone” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available
OS Installed on KashodhaniPhone
5.1.1 (9B206)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
5.0 (9A334)
4.3
4.2
4.1
4.0.2
4.0.1
4.0

Answer (score 2):

those messages seem to indicate that you have iOS 5.1.1 on your phone, but you have a version of Xcode that only supports iOS 5.0 or lower.

if you do not see the "iOS 5.1 Library" in your "Preferences" Downloads tab under Documentation, then you probably need to download the latest developer tools.

[image: Xcode preferences downloads documentation]