# Is there a way to add a device to a provisioning profile without using Apple developer portal?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, provisioning-profile

Apple developer portal is down since more than a day, is there a way to add a device to a provisioning profile without using http://developer.apple.com/iphone/?

I am wondering if XCode 4.5 has some functionality that allows this, however, from Apple's [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment.html) it does not seem possible.

EDIT: I tried using XCode 4.5 to add the device to the profile by clicking "use this device for development" which should, I believe, add the device to the wildcard provisioning profile. However it does not seem to work and I get the following:

[image]

I believe that the error might be caused from the server being down because I do not get any list of "Xcode Supported iOS Versions". There are [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135661/the-version-of-ios-on-kashodhaniphone-does-not-match-any-of-the-versions-of-io) tackling this but I believe this is a different USE CASE because we are dealing with a situation where Apple developer server is down and hence it might be that my XCode works fine.

I tried to check for updates in the Preferences->Downloads->Components section but no update seem to be available. IS this normal? Here is what I can see from my tab but I find it strange that there is no iOS 6.0 simulator available...

[image]

Comment: Xcode should add new devices to the wildcard (*) profile automatically

Comment: So do I not need to add the device to the provisioning portal first?

Comment: When I plug in the device and browse it on XCode organizer I find the poption "use for development". I click that and it tells me "The version of iOS on “Whoever's iPhone” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK". The iOS of the iPhone is iOS 6.1.3 and I am using XCode 4.5.2

Comment: Try rebooting the pc and phone, but even if you do it with xcode, it has to connect to the provisioning portal to add the device, and maybe xcode can't connect either.

Comment: Yeah, that's where the issues is. I guess is the second option.. the portal is down completely so no alternative way to do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems iike that the developer server is down since Thursday due to a hacking [attack](http://venturebeat.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/screen-shot-2013-07-21-at-10-55-02-pm.png).

Looks like we will have to wait for a "while" and that there is no way around to this. This is quiet unfortunate as it slows down development and testing, but hopefully they will build a safer system.

http://venturebeat.com/2013/07/22/apple-developer-site-still-down-apple-extending-developer-memberships/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can add devices in a Provisioning Profile without using Apple developer portal.. There is only one place where you can create provisioning profiles or Add devices and that is Developer.apple.com